# Minimize matrix column totals

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, mathematical-optimization

I would like to pick up n (2 in example) columns from matrix. The sum/total of these columns should be minimal.

```
m = Table[Random[], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}];
f[q_] := Module[{}, q1 = Round[q]; Total[Total[m[[All, q1]]]]];
FindMinimum[f[{x, y}], {{x, 1}, {y, 2}}]
```

Thank You for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom@1
m = RandomInteger[4, {3, 4}];
n = 2;

m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The n largest smallest column totals

```
Transpose @ MinimalBy[Transpose @ m, Total, n] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The n smallest row totals

```
MinimalBy[m, Total, n] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, any chance to do it with FindMinimum/NMinimize?

Comment: FindMinimum / NMinimize wouldn' t function here